# Planck-Einstein energy equation for a spin-2 particle?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-gravity

The $$E=hf$$ Planck-Einstein energy equation applies strictly only for SU(2) elementary single particles like the photon. Even when calculating with this equation the rest energy of an electron we assume that electron is transformed to an equivalent energy SU(2) photon thus imputing the equivalent Compton frequency of the electron in the above equation which is the frequency $f$ or wavelength of an SU(2) photon of equal energy with the electron at rest.

We could also say that the Planck-Einstein energy equation above is exclusively made for calculating spin-1 photon energy. If a particle is not a photon and has for a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ like an electron for example then we must first convert to its equivalent energy spin-1 photon by inserting its [Compton frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength) on the equation.

The Planck constant $h$ in the equation is the quantum of angular momentum for a 2π-symmetrical rotation.

Topologically and graphically we could represent in two spatial dimensions space SU(2) a spin-1 photon in its rest frame as a revolving ring like a flywheel with a fixed center in space:

**Spin-1 in SU(2) as a 2π-symmetrical rotation**

[image: rotcirc]

Also notice the above equation calculates the rest energy for a single particle $N=1$. If there are more than one photon then it is re-written as $E=Nhf$ where $N$ is the integer number of photons.

**However my problem is now how the Planck-Einstein energy equation should be applied or re-written for an integer spin particle with spin greater than one? For example for the theoretical spin-2 graviton?**

As far as I know there i no established value for a spin-2 particle graviton equivalent Compton wavelength-frequency to input in the equation. Therefore, for a spin-2 particle the normal Planck-Einstein equation must now adopted for the π-symmetry rotation of a spin-2 particle instead of the normal 2π-symmetry of a spin-1 photon if we ever want to be able in the future to calculate a possible energy for graviton derived from its frequency.

My educated guess would be, that because now the π-symmetry of the spin-2 graviton thus a full 2π rotation made by π thus actually double the frequency of an equivalent 2π-symmetrical rotation therefore for a single spin-2 graviton the Planck-Einstein energy equation should be re-written as:

$$E=2hf.$$

Comment: Personal theories and non-mainstream physics are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The Planck-Einstein energy equation states that frequency and energy are the same thing in fundamental physics, the Planck constant just shows how our daily system of units (classical limit) drastically deviates from the natural choice of units.

**So, the same relation applies to a single graviton without any modification.**

Meanwhile, both massless spin-2 and spin-1 particles have two degrees of freedom (dof), rather than 5 and 3 dof respectively as for the case of massive particles. They don't belong to the little group SO(3), whose projective representation is the SU(2) you mentioned. Their little group is ISO(2). You can read Chapter 2 of Weinberg QFT Vol1 for a formal definition of particles.

Comment: Thanks for you concise answer. My only objection is that the h Planck constant factor is not that trivial as you present it in your answer but fundamental representing the symmetry of the oscillation and energy manifold of the field excitation. In other  words, energy is not just frequency of rotation but the symmetry of the rotation is also important deciding factor of the energy generated.

Comment: Two revolving non-symmetric loops of the same tangential revolution velocity and perimeter-wavelength  but with different manifolds will not generate the same angular momentum and therefore will not have the same energy value. The problem in my opinion  is that spin-2 is not 2π-symmetric and therefore E=hf is not direct applicable in its original form in the case of a spin-2 particle without knowing the  effective Compton frequency of the particle.

Comment: @Markoul11 I'm sorry but I can't grasp the kind of novel ideas you're talking about. For the time being, I'm content with the answer that there is nothing special about the Planck constant.

Comment: Well, the important thing is to understand is that E=hf represents circular 2π rotation oscillation. Any other shape deviating from the circle of a closed loop rotation and dynamics and the this equation is not anymore applicable unless you know the effective circular angular frequency  of the rotation that will produce the same energy with the twisted loop rotation.

Comment: @Markoul11 is this closed loop rotation a construct of your creation and imagination or is it an established concept in the science community? I've never heard of such things. (I haven't leaned string theory so... )

Comment: Spin is important and defined by h constant and the spin number of the particle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACZC_XEyg9U

Comment: @Markoul11 spin doesn’t refute the trivialness of Planck constant. The definition and physical consequence of spin has nothing to do with h. Every physical consequence of h is absorbed into the Bohr magneton.

Comment: @Markoul11 In SI units, h has been recently set to a fixed value, no longer a measured quantity. Also, I’m not sure from which part of the video you draw your argument. If you’re really serious about physics you should read textbook. The video is great though for showing Dirac’s belt trick, which is also novel to me.

Comment: I do not know what you are talking about these whole SI units story of yours?!  The h/2π is the fundamental quanta of angular momentum L and has angualar momentum units in SI (look it up in WP), which makes then KE=hω/2π=hf rotational energy. All I am seeing now is that in the case of spin-2 π-symmetry rotation you have t

Comment: All I am seeing now is that in the case of spin-2, π-symmetry rotation instead of the spin-1 normal 2π symmetry you get two full rotations every π therefore a boost of two. Thus for spin-2 particles the equation should be re-written as E=2hf to include the boost. If now you regard that the spin quantum property of the particles has nothing to do with rotation motion kinetic energy that is your right but there is no actual prove against it and this is just a mathematical interpretation of the theory and not physical. We do not know what actually the particle's flux is doing?